# Animate to top value when element has a bottom value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate an element that is absolutely positioned and positioned bottom and left to a position top and right.

CSS

```
.obj{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 200px; 
}
```

JS

```
$('.obj').click(function(event){
    $(this).animate({top:'15%', right: '300px' }, 400).css({'bottom': '', 'left': ''});
});
```

The problem with what I currently have is that some browsers (Chrome/Safari) will fire the CSS as it animates which leads to the object jumping across the screen.

**EDIT:** It seems to clear the bottom and left value, then animates from `top: 0, right: 0`.

Also, I can't put the `.css()` in the complete function of the `.animate()` because the current bottom and left positioning affects how it animates.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: does it produce the same result when you chain the css function before the animate() ?

Comment: Yes, either way you chain it, it seems to be setting the `.css()` first in Chrome/Safari.

Comment: by "fliying" to you mean jumping instantly? if yes, I don't see how I can be otherwise with this css call. Can you describe what happens when you remove it, or provide an example online (with JSFiddler for example)

Comment: Haha, yes jumping seems to describe it better. It jumps from it's current position to `top:0, right:0` and animates from there.

Comment: As I said before, I don't see how it behaves now and how it should be without some sample. So what I think could be done here is trying to use an "absolutize" function (basically, it's from prototypeJS, but it has ports in jQuery). You can either: 1)converts all beginning and ending positions to absolutized coordinates (left and top) which will ease the translation, or 2) write your own right_absolutize() function which will convert the begining coordinates to top%-rightPx coordinates. That's quite brute force but All I can think of now without online sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can base your animation relative to the starting location, or in this case the bottom left to get it to slide better in chrome.

```
$('div.obj').click(function(event){
    var obj = $(this);
    var top = obj.context.offsetTop;
    var right = obj.context.offsetParent.clientWidth - (obj.context.offsetLeft*2);
    obj.animate({bottom:top+'px', left: right+'px' }, 400);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I've yet to implement it, but I think calculating the bottom and left based on the top and right should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a timeout function on the effect o that the CSS has time to load :)
Google it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this.animate({top:'15%', right: '300px' }, 400).css({'bottom': '', 'left': ''});
```

Should be:

```
$(this).animate({top:'15%', right: '300px' }, 400).css({'bottom': '', 'left': ''});
```

should it not?

Comment: That was a typo when I was writing it in here. Fixed, but problem still exists.